# 'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXBtu.png)

this is the code i use for trying to add an new member to my Lid table in the database. the problem i get everytime is that i get the following error:
'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.' What may cause it to give that error?

Comment: Please include code as text rather than as image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Don't know about the specific error, but you want to connect your connection to your sqlcommand for starters, and then actually fill that command with an actual command text. Right now you are trying to execute an empty command (with two parameters) without a connection to any database.

Comment: Wrong close parenthesys. It should be _new(......)).Value = ...._ but as explained above this is only the first error. And again post code as text not as images

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the issue is. This expression `new SqlParameter(...).Value = "whatever"` does not return anything. You are passing nothing to the `Add` method of the collection. Do it like this: `var p1 = new SqlParameter (); p1.Value = "whatever"` then pass `p1` to the collection: `Add(p1)`. Please add your code to your question because people like me want to copy paste it and fix it; hard to do that from an image.

Comment: We really don't like pictures of code here.  Post it as text with a four space indent.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an instance of SqlParameter to the Parameters list, but instead you pass an assignment expression that evaluates to the righthand string that was assigned to the lefthand (SqlParameter.Value) as per C# specification.

> The result of an assignment expression is the value assigned to the left-hand operand. The type of the right-hand operand must be the same as the type of the left-hand operand or implicitly convertible to it. (see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator))

The following would set the value parameter and pass the instance by means of object initialization syntax, see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers). Furthermore, you could (should) make use of convinient syntax like "using statements" to guarantee the closure of the connection.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {  
     con.Open();     
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)) {
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = someValueHere });
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param3", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = someValueHere2 });
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Comment: Or use the `SqlParameterCollection.Add` overloads which elides the constructor usage (at least in user code). They then become `cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "myValue";` where `Add` actually returns the newly constructed parameter so you don't need the initializer

Comment: That SQLCommand object also needs to be disposed!

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Had it been without the .Value part, I would prefer it that way, but I much prefer defining the parameter followed by adding it to the list. Is your approach prefered by some standard?

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow ah, looking into it, I was wrong to assume it was just an object you would expect the garbage collector to take fully care of. I fixed it

Comment: It's probably preference but they added those overloads for a reason. Makes things shorter and it's my preferred way and the only way I've seen it in code bases I've worked with